# How do you implement the "add comment" feature used in Stackoverflow for asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, comments

How do I recreate the add comment feature in Stackoverflow using mvc 3 razor (EF4)?

Here's mockup code:

```
<div>add comment</div> 

<ul id="comments">                                          
@foreach (var comment in Model) {                           
    <li>@comment</li>                                       
}                                                           
</ul>                                                       

<form method="post" id="commentForm"                        
      action="@Url.Action("AddComment")">                   

    @Html.TextArea("Comment", new { rows = 5, cols = 50 })   
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
</form>
```

How do I go about with the Add/Edit comments via ajax/jquery? Should it be a partial view?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how StackOverflow does it, but there are a few ways to achieve the same thing.

Usually, you'd write some jQuery in your page to intercept the form post and post the data using ajax instead.

1. You could post to a Web API or just an action that returns JSON. On the server, add the comment to whatever data store you're using and reply with either a success result or details of the saved comment (up to you).  When complete, render the new entry on the client side using jQuery - in your case, just add a new li with the comment. OR
2. You could post to an action that returns a partial view. Save the comment, update the collection, then render the partial view.  In your jQuery, you could replace the whole comments section with the new content.

It's a very broad question and there are many other ways to do it.  You could use something like SignalR to push new comments from the server (to make it realtime), and you could use a JS templating framework like Knockout JS so you're only dealing with a template and an array of objects.